# How to take user location quickly android

Tags: android, location

I need to how to take user current location quickly when app is opened. I know the method of taking the user current location. But it take some time to take location. How to improve that?

Answer (score 1):

try this
 
Use Google Play Services FusedLocationApi.
its quick and relaible.
Refer here:- https://coderzpassion.com/android-location-using-google-play-services/

Comment: Current app I use this method. But sometime it take several minute to take location. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: No I need to get current location when i press a button. But it take some time and not accurate most of the time

Answer (score 1):

You can use Location Manager. 
Here is the code.

```
double latitude;
double longitude;
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    };

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}
```

put the methods above inside oncreate() and you may want to decalre latitude and longitude as private members 
also you can change LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER by LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER but this last will take a moment to get the data from GPS satellite . the first one (Network provider) takes only a few seconds to get the current location and don't forget to put permissions into your manifest file

Answer (score 0):

The time it takes to get user location can vary since it depends on several factors. GPS satellite availability, Wifi or cell tower availability and the quality of the device can affect the location obtaining process so there is nothing you can do here to speed up the process.

If you want to know the user's whereabouts and doesn't really care about the accuracy of the location, then you should get "Last Known Location" of the user. This will give you the location saved by the system during last location request made by any of the apps installed on the device. As you are already using FusedLocationApi, you can do the following to obtain last location in the onConnected() callback.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        // use the location
    } else {
        // in very rare case, last location can be null. In which case 
        // you have to request location update here
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know the method to improve the location accuracy upto 10m ?